# IIS 7 redirect 301 domain A to domain B

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

How can I redirect(301) in IIS7? 
I'm trying redirect link form 'domainA.com/link_A' to 'domainB.com/link_B' using rewrite rules in web.config. How can I do this for selected links?
It is right?

```
    <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainA.com/link_A$ />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainB.com/link_B{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the "link_A" part to the URL, since the HTTP_HOST only matches the domain name. So your rule should look something like this

```xml
<rule name="rewriting" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="link_A" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainA.com$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainB.com/link_B{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I would like to know what is best way to rewrite ~400 links. I should use 400 times this code in web.config or it's more optimized way to do this?

Comment: If there is some kind of pattern between the links on DomainA and DomainB you can use the rule variables in the redirect URL. I have actually made a small error in my answer that uses that. Instead of redirecting to www.domainB.com/link_B it would actually redirect to www.domainB.com/link_Blink_A, since the `{R:0}` part would insert the matched URL in the redirect URL.

Comment: Why was the answer unaccecpted after being accepted?